# Convert Company Entity to Finance Entity

Tags: entity

Is there an easy/straightforward way to get the corresponding Finance entity given a Company entity if it’s available?

I have a hack-y fix just  y taking the “Name” property for the Company and passing that into FinanceData though this does not work 100% of the time.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use the *CommonShares* property of a company entity to retrieve the associated financial entities (assuming the data are available).  For example:

```
$company = Interpreter["Company"]["Apple"]
```

[image: company entity]

```
$financials = $company["CommonShares"]
```

[image: financial entities]

```
Through[$financials["Symbol"]]
```

[image: financial symbols]

```
$financials[[1]]["Properties"]
```

[image: financial entity properties]

```
$financials[[1]]["Price"]
```

[image: financial entity's price]

```
FinancialData[$financials[[1]], {{2022,3,1}, {2022,3,31}}] // DateListPlot
```

[image: financial entity's closing price plot]